# what method to use for firebase addDoc with custom doc id?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

/**

- Add a new document to specified `CollectionReference` with the given data,
- assigning it a document ID automatically.
- 
- @param reference - A reference to the collection to add this document to.
- @param data - An Object containing the data for the new document.
- @returns A `Promise` resolved with a `DocumentReference` pointing to the
- newly created document after it has been written to the backend (Note that it
- won't resolve while you're offline).
  */
  export declare function addDoc(reference: CollectionReference, data: WithFieldValue): Promise<DocumentReference>;
  /**
- Returns a new map where every key is prefixed with the outer key appended
- to a dot.
  */

Comment: the documentation said doc id is automatically generated, i want to supply custom doc id

Comment: Please checkout [ask] and [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 2):

I understand that you want to add a new document to a collection with a document ID that you specify. You should you use the `setDoc()` method as follows:

```
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 

await setDoc(doc(db, "cities", "new-city-id"), data);
```

This code will add a document in the `cities` collection with the `new-city-id` Document ID.

This is explained in the Firestore [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document).

Comment: Hey downvoter, how could I improve my answer?

Comment: (I am not the downvoter) Maybe it's because your answer "adds or replaces" and they think the question implies "add" only